# Fair thread scheduler time base in Racket

Tags: multithreading, scheme, racket, scheduler

How is the time slice allocated for a thread calculated in Racket (formerly PLT Scheme)? E.g. "each thread has 16 ms to run, then switch to the next". Is there a variable to set, or a command line parameter to change the value? I didn't find any information about this in the docs. Diving into the sources now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't have much in the documentation to look for, so the sources are your best bet.  In general, look for mentions of "fuel" which (IIRC) is allocated for each thread, and a thread can change if the current one is blocking for IO or something similar.

Comment: Found it: The constant MZ_THREAD_QUANTUM_USEC is set to 10000, so the time base used by the scheduler is 10 ms. Now I've got something to play with :) Thanks!